# How to get the EXIF PHP extension working on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

I'm using [exif](/questions/tagged/exif) data to carry captions for my images.

Using `exif_read_data` on localhost worked fine (with Apache on Ubuntu), but Heroku reports:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_read_data() in /app/path/to/files.

I'm not really sure what to do here, looking at the error message it would appear that EXIF functions are not installed/enabled on my Heroku app.

Can it be added or enabled?

Answer (score 13):

You are correct that the EXIF functions are not *enabled* on your Heroku app.

Since the "new" PHP buildpack, all that is needed to enable extension is to [define the required extensions in the `composer.json` file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages).

In the case of the EXIF that would be:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-exif":"*"
    }
}
```

This is covered in the Heroku devcenter in [the "Using optional extensions" section of the article for PHP support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions).

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: Make sure to run `composer update` after adding that line and commit your lockfile otherwise Heroku won't enable it. Also [full list of extensions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions)

Comment: @Potherca , the link for the article should now link to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions , which is specific to extensions. That old link just links to php ini values, which is also important.

Answer (score 0):

`exif` extension is not enabled in your `heroku` environment.

You need support for `exif` in order to use its functions. In php.ini you will find these two lines are the ones that do it:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

And of course the dlls should be available in the correct folder - For linux instead of `.dll` they would be `.so`. I am not sure how it works in heroku. Maybe you can get their tech support to check these?

Comment: Alright I put my PHP.ini in /www/etc/ and re-commited.  However I am still getting the PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_read_data() in /app/... not really certian what to do.

Comment: @user1789778, no that is not how you do it. First of all, there is only one php.ini in the environment, and it is already there since your php script is running. Secondly, if you make any change to the php.ini you need to restart the server or cold boot or whatever cloud env does. What you are doing will not suffice. First thing you can do is print `phpinfo()` and find where the `php.ini`is, then in the same page look if a section called `exif` exists

Comment: Old question/old answer but I don't think generic server answers solve this heroku specifi issue.